# Load balancing for WCF Component

Tags: .net, wcf, load-balancing

Is there any way to balance load for WCF component. What I want to do is host same WCF service on 2 machines and add introduce a load balancer. can I do this programatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to load balancing, in WCF, Depending on the binding that you are using you need to change the default binding settings. Microsoft has more details in their article on WCF Load Balancing where they discuss settings for NetTcpBinding, WSHttpBinding, WSDualHttpBinding, and BasicHttpBinding.

[Load balance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730128.aspx)